# Material theming - how can I generates shades?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, material-design, theming

everybody!
I want to create a custom theme using Angular Material theming,but with my own 3 colors.
For their themes, they create shades like this:

```
$mat-red: (
  50: #ffebee,
  100: #ffcdd2,
  200: #ef9a9a,
  300: #e57373,
  400: #ef5350,
  500: #f44336,
  600: #e53935,
  700: #d32f2f,
  800: #c62828,
  900: #b71c1c,
  A100: #ff8a80,
  A200: #ff5252,
  A400: #ff1744,
  A700: #d50000,
  contrast: (
    50: $dark-primary-text,
    100: $dark-primary-text,
    200: $dark-primary-text,
    300: $dark-primary-text,
    400: $dark-primary-text,
    500: $light-primary-text,
    600: $light-primary-text,
    700: $light-primary-text,
    800: $light-primary-text,
    900: $light-primary-text,
    A100: $dark-primary-text,
    A200: $light-primary-text,
    A400: $light-primary-text,
    A700: $light-primary-text,
  )
);
```

How can I generate them for my custom colors?Because I cannot figure it out.
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Does anybody have a better idea that this one?https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/custom-theming-in-angular-material-a9b0d7cd68a8

Answer (score 0):

I've used this site to generate shades for custom colors. I included some examples for you:

http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?purple=%233f51b5&yellow=%2326a69a&themename=Stackblitz-Example

There is a down arrow on the bottom of the page. If you click that, you can pick the output format you would like (e.g. Material UI(React), Angular 2, etc).